# Why am I getting 413 request entity too large error when I make post request in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, api, dart

Im trying to make post request in flutter as shown below

```
uploadImage() async {
    print('inside uploadimage function');
    
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => setState((){isLoading = true;}  ));
    final request = http.MultipartRequest(
      "POST", Uri.parse('http://server/upload'));
    final headers = {"Content-type":"multipart/form-data"};
    request.files.add( http.MultipartFile('image1',
    widget.imagefile1!.readAsBytes().asStream(),widget.imagefile1!.lengthSync(),
    filename: widget.imagefile1!.path.split("/").last));
   
    request.files.add(http.MultipartFile('image2',
    imageFile!.readAsBytes().asStream(),imageFile!.lengthSync(),
    filename: imageFile!.path.split("/").last));
    request.headers.addAll(headers);

    final response = await request.send();
    http.Response res = await http.Response.fromStream(response);
    print('statuscode:');
    print(response.statusCode);
    print(response.reasonPhrase);    
  }
```

as a response I get error 413 request entity too large but when I make a request through POSTMAN i can successfully make a request with status 200 OK. as shown below
[image: image1]

I'm not able to figureout why this happening any help or suggestion on how to solve this will be highly appreciated thanks

Comment: Probably not related, but there's a convenience static to create a `MultipartFile` from disk - check out: https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/MultipartFile/fromPath.html  As your server seems to accept http, grab a packet capture of the postman request and the dart request and compare them.